# In cocos2d, is there something paralled to onEnter and onExit?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I can capture scene change events by its onEnter and onExit methods. But when scene change events takes time, like fade in or fade out, onEnter is called to early (right before the fading) and onExit is called to late (after the fading completed).

I want another onEnter called right after the fading completed and another onExit called right before the fading. Can i?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a second onEnter callback just for transitions, it's called onEnterTransitionDidFinish. But like it has been mentioned, this will only fire if CCScheduler is being used in conjunction with CCSceneTransition.

Comment: Yes, I found that and used. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use a CCSequence with your CCFadeIn and then add a CCCallFunc after it.

onEnter and onExit are to do with CCNode object allocation and removal, not physical views.

Sample code:

```
[scene runAction:[CCSequence actions:
   [CCFadeIn actionWithDuration:0.45f],
   [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:scene selector:@selector(fakeOnEnter:)], nil]];
```

Inside your scene object you will need a method as such,

```
-(void) fakeOnEnter:(id)sender {
  // your code to run after the fadein
}
```

Comment: Not that this isn't a valid tactic, but there is built-in functionality covering this subject.

Comment: That would only work if he is correctly fading between scenes using transition methods for CCDirector, but yes your right, we need more clarification from him on how he's creating the scenes and bringing them onto the screen.

Comment: You moved the logic from callee to caller. Sorry, it's not solving the problem.